# Cut-off half a torus in a surface plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to plot only half of a torus using `matplotlib`.

This is my approach so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

n = 100

# theta: poloidal angle; phi: toroidal angle
theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, n)
phi   = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, n)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

# R0: major radius; a: minor radius
R0, a = 2., 1.

# torus parametrization
x = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
y = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
z = a * np.sin(theta)

# "cut-off" half of the torus
x[x>0] = np.nan

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.set_zlim(-3,3)
ax1.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,)

# elev: elevation angle in z-plane
# azim: azimuth angle in x,y plane
ax1.view_init(elev=15, azim=0)

plt.show()
```

Doing so, gives me indeed half a torus, but one of the cut surfaces is not clear, as can be seen in the figure (it is the left cut surface which is problematic here). [image]

Any ideas how to make a clean cut surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutting off surfaces with `nan`s will usually do that. This is due to the fact that patches of the surface are drawn using linear interpolation over a subset of the input data, and having `nan`s on the boundary will lead to `nan` results for values for some edge patches.

In your specific case you can just limit your toroidal angle to half a torus:

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n) 
phi   = np.linspace(0, np.pi, n)
```

You'll have to set manual x/y limits as well for a pretty aspect ratio:

```
ax1.axis([-3, 3]*2)
```

[image: result]

There's a very general but hands-on alternative by passing an explicit array of `facecolors` to `plot_surface`, and manipulating the transparency of the values inside. This will be much uglier than the default unless you work hard, since shading will be missing with flat colours. Here's a very basic (and ugly) example for what I mean:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

n = 100 

# theta: poloidal angle; phi: toroidal angle 
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n) 
phi   = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n) 
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi) 

# R0: major radius; a: minor radius 
R0, a = 2., 1. 

# torus parametrization 
x = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi) 
y = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi) 
z = a * np.sin(theta) 

# "cut-off" half of the torus using transparent colors 
c = np.full(x.shape + (4,), [0, 0, 0.85, 1])  # shape (nx, ny, 4)
c[x>0, -1] = 0 # set these to transparent 

fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax1.set_zlim(-3,3) 
ax1.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=c, rstride=5, cstride=5,)

# elev: elevation angle in z-plane 
# azim: azimuth angle in x,y plane 
ax1.view_init(elev=15, azim=0) 

plt.show()
```

[image: facecolors example result]

Comment: `phi   = np.linspace(0, np.pi, n)` is the same as doing `y[y>0] = np.nan` instead of `x[x>0] = np.nan`. Although due to the symmetry, your answer actually solves the problem, it yet doesn't comment on what's going wrong with the `x[x>0] = np.nan`.

Comment: @Bazingaa yeah, I guess one could add a pi/2 shift to make it exactly the same. I thought it was obvious that cutting off values will meddle with interpolation used by `plot_surface`. I'll try to elaborate on that.

Comment: well, that was easy (my guess was trying to make a "softer" or smoother interpolation of `plot_surface`)

Comment: @Alf another, more general but messier option is to pass an explicit array of `facecolors` to `plot_surface`, but then you have to decide about the colours yourself so I won't add that to my answer considering the above works for you.

Comment: @AndrasDeak interesting, haven't though about that

Comment: @Alf I update with a simple example anyway, but as you can see it doesn't look very good. I usually do this together with a `cmap`, then colours are still pretty (but not something that corresponds to the visualization of a 3d object rather than some kind of dataset).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see what you mean, thanks for the insight!